# Scaling Socket.IO across multiple servers

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I've been searching around looking for help on setting up a multi-server cluster for a Node.js Socket.IO install. This is what I am trying to do:

- Have 1 VIP in an F5 loadbalancer, pointing to `n` number of Node servers running Express, and Socket.IO
- Have client connect to that 1 VIP via `io.connect` and then have it filter to one the of the servers behind the loadbalancer.
- When a message is emitted on any one of those servers, it is is sent to all users who are listening for that event and connect via the other servers.

For example - if we have Server A, Server B and Server C behind LB1 (F5), and User A is connected to Server A, User B is connected to Server B and User C is connected to Server C.

In a "chat" scenario - basically if a message is emitted from Server A to `message` event - Server B and C should also send the message to their connected client. I read that this is possible with using `socket-io.redis`, but it needs a Redis box - which server should that be install on? If all the servers are connected to the same Redis box - does this work automatically?

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: It seems like a good solve for this would be to enable peer-to-peer communication between different socket.io instances on the express servers, this way they can all stay in sync with one another. You can do this using something like [scuttlebutt](https://github.com/dominictarr/scuttlebutt) and with its [event emitter](https://github.com/dominictarr/scuttlebutt#scuttlebuttevents)

Comment: Using the `socket.io-redis` adapter will indeed automatically (with some configuration) achieve what you're looking for. It does not matter which node your Redis server will listen on, as long as all of the Socket.IO instances are subscribed to it.

Comment: Have you read this: http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/?  If so, what did you not understand about it?  It appears to be designed for your particular situation.

Comment: Yes - I should have tried this before, but @hexacyanide was correct - it works exactly out of the box as  long as everyone is attached to the the same redis box. For anyone coming to this post later - it just works. sorry for wasting everyone's time :-(

Comment: If you're done with your question, you can either answer it yourself or delete it rather than just leave it sit here.

Comment: @gregavola I'm facing this exact problem. On which server did you end up running the redis box? The way I see it, redis box could be running either on VIP or any of the nodes. However, if the node with redis would stop functioning in any way, the entire cluster would stop working. The idea to run redis on VIP is not very appealing to me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to this question is that you must set up a single Redis server that is either outside your SocketIO cluster - and have all nodes connect to it.

Then you simply add this at the top of your code and it just works magically without any issues.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

Comment: socket.io-redis seem's to be deprecated in favor of @socket.io/redis-adapter - https://socket.io/docs/v4/redis-adapter