# Multiple websockets onto multiple servers: how do they communicate?

Tags: node.js, websocket, multiprocessing

I have a node server accepting websocket connections from the clients. Each client can broadcast a message to all of the other clients.

**UPDATE:** I am using https://github.com/websockets/ws as my library of choice.

At the moment, the server has an array with all of the connections. Each connection has a `tabId`. When one of the client emits a message, I go through all of the connections and check: if the connection's tabId doesn't match, I send the message to the client.

For loading issues, I am facing the problem of having to have more than one server. So, there will be say two servers, each one with a number of clients.

How do I make sure that a message gets broadcast to *all* of the websocket clients, and not only the ones connected to the same server?

One possible solution I thought is to have the connections stored on a database, where each record has the `tabId` *and* the `serverId`. However, even a simple broadcast gets tricky as messages to "local" sockets are easy to broadcast (the socket is local and available) whereas messages to "remote" sockets are tricky, and would imply intra-server communication.

Is there a good pattern to solve this? Surely, this is something that people face every day.

Comment: [_"Adapter to enable broadcasting of events to multiple separate socket.io server nodes"_](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis)

Comment: [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821899/scaling-socket-io-across-multiple-servers)

Comment: I specified that I am not using socketio but ws

Comment: @Merc - Some platforms use a pub/sub database such as Redis to solve this issue. You can do a quick search for different pub/sub patterns. The Array pattern you currently employ is a very basic pattern that can't really scale beyond the process.

Comment: OK. But... if I have the servers S1, S2 and S3, and I have clients C1 connected to S1 and C2 connected to S2, if C1 wants to communicate to C2, C1 will emit to S1, and then S1 will need to "talk" somehow to S2 in order to emit the event... is that right?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a messagequeue like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).

When a client logs in to your server, create a consumer which listens to a queue which will receive messages directed to that particular client. And when the clients are sending messages, just use a publisher to publish them to the recipients queue.

This way it doesn't matter and you don't need to know on which nodes the clients are on, or if they jump from a node to another.